# In Retrieve and rank how to tell service that the words are of same context

Tags: solr, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

For example I want to query "tell me fever symptoms" but it breaks "fever" and "symptoms"  which ultimately gives some wrong results.

In Apache solr we can query with double quotes but in RnR it does not make any difference.

Also sometimes even ground truth queries are returned with the wrong result.

Suppose "what are the symptoms of fever" is my query then solr indexes "what", "are", "the", "symptoms", "of", "fever". Is it a good practice to add the what,why,how etc to stopwords because doing so will change the meaning of the query.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Soooo .. what is your question here?

Comment: Phrase Queries or shingles are usually the way to handle this in Solr - boosting terms that occur close to each other. Have you tried any solutions?